# Using Webcam as Remote Security Cam

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, webcam

I've seen [products](http://blog.logitech.com/2010/08/03/new-logitech-alert-video-security-system/) out there that let you view a security camera in your home remotely via an iPhone app.

But I was wondering if I could build a cheaper solution. I would like to use my built in webcam on my MacBook as a remote security cam (really, I'd just like to be able to check in on our dog at home while we are away, security being a secondary concern) and be able to view it on my iPhone and potentially on my work PC as well. Although, if it was just working for the iPhone that would be plenty enough.

Is there any software/apps out there that will do that currently?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, there are lots of applications that allow you to remotely view a feed from any camera connected to a Mac, including the built-in camera: [EvoCam](http://www.evological.com/evocam.html), [RemoteSight](http://www.bensoftware.com/remotesight/), [SecuritySpy](http://www.securityspy.com/), or if you're handy with command-line tools, [iSightCapture](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/18598/isightcapture).

Most of these products stream the feed from the camera to a web server, which you can then view on your iPhone or work computer.

Comment: There's also OnCue, www.theoncueapp.com

Comment: @jakev I was going to advise the freebie [iSentry](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/41555/isentry) but that onCue is by far the best one! It even works for free (I think) except there is a message you have to press "ok" to keep recording... I haven't bothered too much as I quickly shoved the U$30 which I think is worth it.

Comment: Don't open the OnCue link. Takes you to a sketchy website.